# Google Assistant on rgb matrix with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rgb, google-assistant-sdk, spectrum

firstly I want to specify I'm a beginner:these days I started working on a project which seems to be much more harder than I expectated. The entire project is to mount Google Assistant on my raspberry pi 1 B+ and show the spectrum analyser of the audio output(google assistant voice) on a rgb panel 32x128 px.
To let raspberry pi communicating with the panel I'm using the Adafruit RGB Matrix + Real Time Clock HAT. 
About the google assitant there is a long process, which i completed, but that one is not the hardest part. The big question is to find the way how to read the spectrum analyser of the output voice of the Assistant and show it on the panel. (The panel can work with the module RGB-MATRIX created by Adafruit).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for everyone who will answer.

Marco

P.S my only knowledge is in python, so I'm trying to move the project with python only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the Google Assistant SDK you will be able to get the direct waveform of the Google Assistant voice in the time domain. That is, you'll get the amplitude at each point in time (using your audio settings for the rate).

In order to do a 'spectrum analysis', you will need to convert your time-based amplitudes into frequencies. This is done in signal processing through a Fourier transform over a period of time, often a few milliseconds, to get the frequencies for that sample.

In many applications you'll use a technique known as the "fast Fourier transform" (FFT), which is fast and practical. There are [some tutorials](https://pythontic.com/visualization/signals/fouriertransform_fft) online for how to compute it in Python using numpy. Following that guide, rather than plotting the frequencies you could compute the `fourierTransform` and display the data on a 32x32 grid.